# Newton's Method Converges in Mathematica for non-convergent functions

Tags: functions

In mathematica I set `f[x_] := Sign[x] Sqrt[Abs[x]]` and then I solved it in a root finding for Newton's method by doing `FindRoot[f[x], {x, 1}, Method -> "Newton"]` which returns `{x -> 0.}`. This is all fine and good as yes the root is obviously at `f[0]`; however, when iterating newton's method for $f(x)=\text{Sign}(x)\sqrt{|x|}$ for the initial value $x_0 = 1$ you get $x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$ which turns into $x_{k+1} = x_k-2\text{Sign}(x)|x|$. We would get $x_1 = 1 - 2*\text{Sign}(1)*|1| = -1$ then we get $x_2 = -1 - 2*\text{Sign}(-1) |-1| = -1 + 2 = 1$ and it obviously oscillates at $\pm 1$ but never converges to zero; yet mathematica converges this to 0 immediately, is there a way to truly iterate newton's method in Mathematica?

Comment: interesting observation. We can surmise `Method -> "Newton"` is not strictly pure newton but has some tweak to avoid such oscillation. What exactly is the question though? You can implement it yourself obviously.

Comment: see here for diy implementations: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34229/2079

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You can always write your own Newton-Raphson solver. It's not even a particularly difficult exercise. But why bother? The built-in solvers are better than anything you could write.

Comment: little correction, the linked page pertains to a modified newton method, but should give the idea.  The other caveat here, mathematica does not nicely deal with analytic derivatives of `Abs` and `Sign` so it will take bit of work to show your exact oscillation result.

Comment: I did it also not using `Abs` and `Sign` which ended up being `g[x_] := -Sqrt[-x] + HeavisideTheta[x] (Sqrt[-x] + Sqrt[x])`. Then `FullSimplify[g[x]/g'[x]]=2x` thus making Newton's method the analytical `Subscript[x, k+1]=Subscript[x, k]-2*Subscript[x, k]` yet mathematica still returns `{x -> 0. + 0. I}` for `FindRoot[g[x], {x, 1}, Method -> "Newton"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that neither [`Sign`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sign.html) nor [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) is differentiable so that Newton's Method may not be applied to the OP's problem in its given form.

*Caveat:*
I am assuming this is a toy example, to show that the unadorned Newton's method fails on some functions.  Normally, `FindRoot` uses step control to try to avoid certain common traps in using Newton's Method.  One can turn off the protections with the option setting `"StepControl" -> None` as shown below.

```
Needs["Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`"]

FindRootPlot[Sign[x] Sqrt[Abs[x]], {x, 1}, 
 Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we define the functions in terms of differentiable functions, one can invoke Newton's Method successfully:

```
sign[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {-1, x < 0}}, 0];
abs[x_] := Sqrt[x^2]; 
FindRootPlot[sign[x] Sqrt[abs[x]], {x, 1}, 
 Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see the steps, we can [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) them:

```
Reap@FindRoot[sign[x] Sqrt[abs[x]], {x, 1}, 
  Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> None}, StepMonitor :> Sow[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The steps oscillate between `±1`.

Comment: Please replace `sign[x] Sqrt[abs[x]]` with uppercase letters.

Comment: @Willinski. Michael is defining special versions of those functions to make his point. The replacement you request would invalidate his answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg Oh, yes! My blind eyes!